# Splitting strings in C++

Tags: c++, string, token

How do you split a string into tokens in C++?

Comment: dup of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/236129/c-how-to-split-a-string

Comment: How about some of the examples from the following: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/Tokenizer.aspx They are very efficient and somewhat elegant. The String Toolkit Library makes complex string processing in C++ simple and easy.

Answer (score 16):

this works nicely for me :), it puts the results in `elems`. `delim` can be any `char`.

```
std::vector<std::string> &split(const std::string &s, char delim, std::vector<std::string> &elems) {
    std::stringstream ss(s);
    std::string item;
    while(std::getline(ss, item, delim)) {
        elems.push_back(item);
    }
    return elems;
}
```

Comment: Why return elems. When it is passed into the function as reference parameter?

Comment: oh, just for convenience. So if you need you can do something like:
split(line, ',', elems).at(2);
it's entirely unnecessary to return it.

Comment: This does not handle empty delimited strings correctly, e.g. split(",", ',') should return two empty strings, but the code above just returns one. This can be solved by initializing ss with "s + delim" and handling the special case that an empty string should return an empty list (rather than a list with one empty string).

Answer (score 5):

With [this Mingw distro](http://nuwen.net/mingw.html#download) that includes Boost:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <ostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <boost/algorithm/string.hpp>
using namespace std;
using namespace boost;

int main() {
    vector<string> v;
    split(v, "1=2&3=4&5=6", is_any_of("=&"));
    copy(v.begin(), v.end(), ostream_iterator<string>(cout, "\n"));
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use the C function [strtok](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/strtok.html):

```
/* strtok example */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main ()
{
  char str[] ="- This, a sample string.";
  char * pch;
  printf ("Splitting string \"%s\" into tokens:\n",str);
  pch = strtok (str," ,.-");
  while (pch != NULL)
  {
    printf ("%s\n",pch);
    pch = strtok (NULL, " ,.-");
  }
  return 0;
}
```

The [Boost Tokenizer](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_37_0/libs/tokenizer/index.html) will also do the job:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<boost/tokenizer.hpp>
#include<string>

int main(){
   using namespace std;
   using namespace boost;
   string s = "This is,  a test";
   tokenizer<> tok(s);
   for(tokenizer<>::iterator beg=tok.begin(); beg!=tok.end();++beg){
       cout << *beg << "\n";
   }
}
```

Comment: Watch out for strtok in multi-threaded code.
http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/1363

Answer (score 3):

Try using stringstream:

```
std::string   line("A line of tokens");
std::stringstream lineStream(line);

std::string token;
while(lineStream >> token)
{
}
```

Check out my answer to your last question:
[C++ Reading file Tokens](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/275355/c-reading-file-tokens#275405)

Answer (score 3):

See also boost::split from [String Algo library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_37_0/doc/html/string_algo/reference.html#header.boost.algorithm.string.split_hpp)

```
string str1("hello abc-*-ABC-*-aBc goodbye");
vector<string> tokens;
boost::split(tokens, str1, boost::is_any_of("-*")); 
// tokens == { "hello abc","ABC","aBc goodbye" }
```

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how complex the token delimiter is and if there are more than one.  For easy problems, just use std::istringstream and std::getline.  For more complex tasks or if you want to iterate the tokens in an STL-compliant way, use Boost's Tokenizer.  Another possibility (although messier than either of these two) is to set up a while loop that calls std::string::find and updates the position of the last found token to be the start point for searching for the next.  But this is probably the most bug-prone of the 3 options.