# How to get a certain element from an input (C++)

Tags: c++

I am new to programming in C++.
I am trying to ask the user an input (for example):

```
std::string numbers;
std::cout << What is your favorite number;
std::cin >> numbers
```

If the user entered

```
1, 2, 3
```

How do I extract only the number "2"? I know in python, you would do something like numbers[1], but is there a same way in C++ as well?

Comment: Read basic input functionality: http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/basic_io/

Comment: @Cristy please don't suggest people to read cplusplus tutorials (And cplusplus in general), contains very bad and old practices.

Comment: Have you tried even building your code? Cause you're missing "" in cout

Comment: Please, review my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can get the length of string by numbers.length().

then you can use for loop.

```
for(int i =0 ; i < numbers.length();i++)
{
  if(numbers[i] == '2')
     // do what you want you do here with 2
}
```

Keep in mind, your cin won't get entire "1, 2, 3" string because of  whitespace. You should use getline instead of cin.

such as..

```
getline(cin, numbers,'\n');
```

Answer (score 3):

So, "what are your favorite numbers?"

The idea is the same as in python or any other language: split the input line by the separator character, trim if you care, and finally get the element you want, if it exists.

- [Splitting a string by a character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10058606/c-splitting-a-string-by-a-character)
- Eventually, [trim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/216823/whats-the-best-way-to-trim-stdstring)
- Finally, you should have a vector of string, and you can get the second with `v[1]` or similar, checking if it exists

Answer (score 1):

To catch a line of numbers:

```
int main()
{
     std::vector<int>    numbers;
     std::string line;
     std::getline(std::cin, line);           // First read the whole line of input

     std::stringstream linestream(line);     // Set up to parse the line
     int               number;
     while(linestream >> number) {           // Read a number
        char x;                              // for the comma
        linestream >> x;                     // remove the comma

        numbers.push_back(number);           // Add to the vector (array)
     }

     // Print the number
     std::cout << "The second number is: " << numbers[1] << "\n";  // vectors are 0 indexed
}
```