# How to convert a part of string into integer?

Tags: c++, string

I know how to convert a complete string into integer(using `std::stoi`). But can you guide me how to extract integer from a string. For example, I want to extract the integer `15` from string `a15a`.

```
string x="a15a";
int a = std::stoi(x);
```

This above method works fine if the integer is at the start of the string. For example, If the value of `string x` is `"15a"`, it converts it into integer the `15`. But it does not work if integer is present somewhere in the middle of the string. How to extract an integer from in between the string.
Thanks.

Comment: First use [substr](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/substr) to extract the numeric part to use with `stoi`.

Comment: Can you give us more details about your input? Is it of a fixed format (i.e. letter, then the number, then possibly other letters)? Do you always have just one part with digits? (i.e. not "a15a21b")?

Comment: Yes my input is a fixed format like this: `"15a16a17"`. I want to extract `15`, `16`, and `17` from it. It has three integers in it.

Comment: @UsamaTahir is the separator always `a` - and always a single character?

Comment: @acraig5075 I like your idea of `substr`. May be I can extract three substrings from my input and store them in integers. For example in `"15a16a17"`, I can use `substr(0,1)`, `substr(3,4)` and `substr(6,7)`.

Comment: First use `std::remove_if` to remove all the letters, then convert the resulting string to integer with `std::atoi`

Comment: yes @Wolf `a` is always a single character.

Comment: @UsamaTahir then you can [split by this char](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10058725/2932052)

Comment: Do you want to handle the negative numbers as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another way: You could replace non-digits with spaces so as to use `stringstring` extraction of the remaining integers directly:

```
std::string x = "15a16a17";
for (char &c : x)
{
    if (!isdigit(c))
        c = ' ';
}

int v;
std::stringstream ss(x);
while (ss >> v)
    std::cout << v << "\n";
```

Output:

```
15
16
17
```

Comment: Wouldn't this make negative numbers appear positive?

Comment: @TobySpeight Yes it would, just like it wouldn't accommodate decimal values either. But then the question doesn't imply that those are considerations.

Comment: I think the question does imply that numbers can be negative (though not fractional), through the use of signed `int` for the result.  If only positive values were useful, that would be an unsigned type, surely?

Answer (score 6):

With C++17 you can use [std::from_chars](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/from_chars) to extract a numeric value from a sequence of characters. You code would look something like:

```
std::string x = "a15a";
int a = 0; // initialize with some value in case parsing fails
std::from_chars(&x[1], &x[3], a); // parse from [first, last) range of chars
```

Note that I've omitted error checking. Read that link to see how to use the return value from the function.

Answer (score 1):

You can check each character using `isdigit()` function to determine if it is a digit or not. Then you can combine sequential digits to extract the integer. This way you can extract numbers from any string not just separated by on specific char.

**Update:**

As mentioned by @Toby I updated the code to handle negative numbers as well.

```
string input="14aaa15d-16fff-fff17";
string tmp = "";
vector<int> output;
for (int i = 0; i < input.size(); ++i)
{
    if (isdigit(input[i]))
    {
        if(i>0 && input[i-1]=='-')
            tmp+='-';
        tmp+=input[i];
    }
    else if(tmp.size()>0)
    {
        output.push_back(stoi(tmp));
        tmp = "";
    }
}

if (tmp.size()>0)
    output.push_back(stoi(tmp));

for (int i = 0; i < output.size(); ++i)
    printf("%d ", output[i]);
```

Output:

```
14
15
-16
17
```

Comment: @TobySpeight It works only for positive numbers (like other answers so far) but you can edit the code to handle negative numbers as well

Answer (score 0):

If it's always the single character `a` that separates decimal numbers, the task changes into "Splitting a string by a character". Here is my adaption of the [accepted answer to the same-name SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10058725/2932052):

```
std::stringstream input("15a16a17");
std::string part;
std::vector<int> numbers;

while(std::getline(input, part, 'a'))
{
   numbers.push_back(std::stoi(part));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it quite simply by using a function to location the first occurrence of a digit in your string. Including `<cstring>` makes `strspn()` available and makes the process trivial.

For example to find the first digit character in `"a15a"` you can simply make the call:

```
    int a;
    size_t off, pos;
    std::string x = "a15a";

    off = strcspn (x.c_str(), "0123456789");    /* get no. chars to 1st digit */
```

`off` now holds the offset to the first digit in `x`. The conversion at that point is simple, but to validate the conversion you must use the `try {...} catch (exception) {...}` format or you will not know whether the value `a` after the attempted conversion is valid or not, e.g.

```
    try {   /* validate using try {..} catch (exception) {..} */
        a = std::stoi(x.c_str() + off, &pos);   /* good conversions, store a */
        std::cout << a << '\n';                 /* output number in "a15a" */
    }
    catch (const std::exception & e) {
        std::cerr << e.what() << '\n';
        return 1;
    }
```

That's all that is required to locate the start of the digits in `x` and then to validate the conversion at `x + off` to arrive at the desired integer value.

Putting it altogether, you would have:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstring>

int main() {

    int a;
    size_t off, pos;
    std::string x = "a15a";

    off = strcspn (x.c_str(), "0123456789");    /* get no. chars to 1st digit */
    try {   /* validate using try {..} catch (exception) {..} */
        a = std::stoi(x.c_str() + off, &pos);   /* good conversions, store a */
        std::cout << a << '\n';                 /* output number in "a15a" */
    }
    catch (const std::exception & e) {
        std::cerr << e.what() << '\n';
        return 1;
    }
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ /bin/stoi_int
15
```

Answer (score 0):

Regex way :

```
#include <regex>
#include <iterator>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
 using namespace std;

std::string subject("a1b2c12d1212e");
try {
  std::regex re("\\d+");
  std::sregex_iterator next(subject.begin(), subject.end(), re);
  std::sregex_iterator end;
  while (next != end) {
    std::smatch match = *next;
    std::cout << "number " << match.str() << "\n";
    next++;
  } 
} catch (std::regex_error& e) {
  // Syntax error in the regular expression
}

 return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```