# Go from end of string to "/" and assign to var C++

Tags: c++, regex

Here is my filepath `my/example/path` I need to capture `/path` and assign it to a variable. I don't know if this involves regex, what is the best way to do this in C++?

Comment: I dont think this require regex just loop through the characters and save the position of `/` each time you encounter it, so at the end you have the last one position and from there you are good to go

Comment: Regular expressions would be overkill here. Read about `std::basic_string::rfind`.

Comment: This might help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10058606/splitting-a-string-by-a-character

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The fun thing is that http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/find_last_of/ has an example which almost exactly what you are looking for.

```
// string::find_last_of
#include <iostream>       // std::cout
#include <string>         // std::string
#include <cstddef>         // std::size_t

void SplitFilename (const std::string& str)
{
  std::cout << "Splitting: " << str << '\n';
  std::size_t found = str.find_last_of("/\\");
  std::cout << " path: " << str.substr(0,found) << '\n';
  std::cout << " file: " << str.substr(found+1) << '\n'; // you will need `found` only
}

int main ()
{
  std::string str1 ("/usr/bin/man");
  std::string str2 ("c:\\windows\\winhelp.exe");

  SplitFilename (str1);
  SplitFilename (str2);

  return 0;
}
```

Output

```
Splitting: /usr/bin/man
 path: /usr/bin
 file: man
Splitting: c:\windows\winhelp.exe
 path: c:\windows
 file: winhelp.exe
```