# C++ string operation

Tags: c++, string, vector

```
string ss = "1-1-10-8-9";
```

There is a string like above.   **I want to add element to string array between "-"**

string vector should be same as below

```
vector<string> str = {"1", "1", "10", "8", "9"};
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Parse (split) a string in C++ using string delimiter (standard C++)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14265581/parse-split-a-string-in-c-using-string-delimiter-standard-c)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Splitting a string by a character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10058606/splitting-a-string-by-a-character)

Comment: Looks like you do **not** want to add anything to the string, but you just want to split the string by given delimiter. In this case it is "-" character. You already have plenty examples available to use and learn from.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>

int main() {

  std::stringstream ss("1-1-10-8-9");

  std::vector<std::string> v;
  std::string s;
  while(std::getline(ss, s, '-')) {
    v.push_back(s);
  }

  return 0;
}
```