# C++ read pipe delimited file

Tags: c++, readfile

I have file1.txt with this information

```
4231650|A|4444
4225642|A|5555
```

I checked the code here for how to read pipe delimited file in C++

[C++ Read file line by line then split each line using the delimiter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3910326/c-read-file-line-by-line-then-split-each-line-using-the-delimiter)

I modified the code a little bit per my needs. The problem is that it reads the first pipe fine but afterwards how do I read rest of the values?

This is my code:

```
std::ifstream file("file1.txt");
    std::string   line;

    while(std::getline(file, line))
    {
        std::stringstream   linestream(line);
        std::string         data;
        std::string         valStr1;
        std::string         valStr2;


        std::getline(linestream, data, '|');  // read up-to the first pipe

        // Read rest of the pipe values? Why did the accepted answer worked for int but not string???
        linestream >> valStr1 >> valStr2;

        cout << "data: " <<  data << endl;
        cout << "valStr1: " <<  valStr1 << endl;
        cout << "valStr2: " <<  valStr2 << endl;
    }
```

Here's the output:

```
Code Logic starts here ...
data: 4231650
valStr1: A|4444
valStr2: A|4444
data: 4225642
valStr1: A|5555
valStr2: A|5555
Existing ...
```

Comment: See also [splitting a string in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/275404/splitting-strings-in-c).

Comment: You have no code to read up to the second pipe! You also don't check if your reads succeed.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I copied and pasted the accepted answer from previous post. and tweeked it a bit for strings instead of int

Comment: @SamB Never cut/paste someone else's code into yours unless you understand it and have personally confirmed that it applies as-is to your problem.

Comment: It's not "it worked with `int`". It's "it worked with tab (whitespace) delimited values".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why did the accepted answer worked for  int but not string?

Because `|` is not a digit and is an implicit delimiter for int numbers. But it is a good char for a string.

Continue doing it in the same way

```
std::getline(linestream, data, '|');
std::getline(linestream, varStr1, '|');
std::getline(linestream, varStr2);
```