# Converting char* to an array of strings by splitting

Tags: c++

I want to convert a `char*` line of commands into a string array. What I tried:

```
void parse(char* cmd, int length) {
    std::string *arguments = nullptr;
    int amount = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        if (cmd[i] == ' ' || cmd[i] == '\t' || cmd[i] == '\n') {
            amount++;
            continue;
        }
        arguments[amount] = cmd[i];
    }
}
```

But I'm not sure about the `std::string *arguments = nullptr;` part. I don't know the amount of arguments in the `cmd` so I'm not sure how to initialize properly the `arguments` array. In C I probably should solve it with malloc but how do I solve it in C++? Also, as I want to return `arguments` and `amount`, how can I pass them as arguments references to the `parse` string?

Comment: @esii Does cmd point to a string?

Comment: Prefer to use `vector`. Avoiding `vector` in C++ similar to avoiding `memset` and `strcmp` in C.

Comment: If your first thought is to use malloc in C, then your first though in C++ should be use use `std::vector` or `std::unique_ptr`

Comment: 'How do I solve it in C++?' Use a vector of strings, `std::vector<std::string> arguments;`. Use `push_back` to add strings to the vector and `push_back` to add characters to the string.

Comment: Usage of `std::istringstream` and `std::vector<std::string>` makes this a trivial operation.

Comment: Ok, I see. As I never used `vector`, is it possible to show how to use in it C++ way?

Comment: The old way is http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strtok/ the new way is don't use char* -- and pretty well covered in the link in the first comment.

Answer (score 4):

You are not allocating any memory for `arguments` to point at. Use `std::vector<std::string>` instead of `std::string*`. Also see [Splitting strings in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/275404/).

Try something more like this:

```cpp
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <cctype>

std::vector<std::string> parse(const char* cmd, int length) {
    std::vector<std::string> arguments;
    const char *start = cmd;
    const char *stop = cmd + length;
    while (start < stop) {
        while ((start < stop) && isspace(*start)) ++start;
        if (start == stop) break;
        const char *end = start + 1;
        while ((end < stop) && !isspace(*end)) ++end;
        arguments.push_back(std::string(start, end-start));
        start = end + 1;
    }
    return arguments;
}
```

[Live Demo](https://ideone.com/FGMOFr)

Alternatively, `operator>>` handles whitespace parsing for you, so you can wrap the `cmd` data inside of a `std::istringstream` and loop through that instead, eg:

```cpp
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <sstream>

std::vector<std::string> parse(char* cmd, int length) {
    std::vector<std::string> arguments;
    std:istringstream iss(std::string(cmd, length));
    std::string s;
    while (iss >> s) {
        arguments.push_back(s);
    }
    return arguments;
}
```

[Live Demo](https://ideone.com/HvvnOO)

Comment: Type of the argument should be changed to `const char *`

Comment: Thank you! I'm trying to pass `char* arguments[MAX];` but for some reason I get a mismatch. Do you know why?

Comment: @vesii That's an array of `char*` but your function takes a `char*`

Comment: @vesii Are you trying to *populate* a `char*[]` array that you pass in, or are you trying to *parse* such an array? You need to be more specific. Please edit your question with more details.