# How to get names?

Tags: c++

I need to get names from one file and write them to another. 
Lines of first file look like this:

```
a001   0 0 :N
a0100  0 0 :N
a1000  0 0 :N
```

Where a*** - name, first 0 - coord X, second 0 - coord Y, and :N - doesn't matter.
Second file that I need to write must contain names from first file and instead first 0 and second 0 must be randoms numbers.
In the end, second file must looks like this:

```
a001  10  150 :N
a0100 0   20  :N
a1000 130 0   :N
```

How can I do this?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: i tried ifstream and ofstream.

Comment: That's not very descriptive. You could say you've tried C++.

Comment: clearly **all** of the io stream library has been put to good use

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To read, try C++'s stream operators to read tokens: [C++ Reading file Tokens](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/275355/c-reading-file-tokens)

To write, try C++'s stream operators with [`setw`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iomanip/setw/) to line up the columns.